# How to creates Tokens in SAML?

Tags: jakarta-ee, saml

I am new to SAML. I want create a TOKEN. Please help me in Creation. what r the steps i have to follow?

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+create+saml+token

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create SAML token for idp-initiated authentication from salesforce are given [here](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=436)

Understand SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) Service [here](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html).

You will use openSAML libraries which can be found [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home;jsessionid=D40953F6D372B15EA1134588C604C5DE).